# add half a day after every week that passes every month

Tags: excel, vba

I want add half a day after every week that passes every month .I wrote this code, but it did not work

```
Sub ()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    x = Range("e2").Value
    y = Range("d2").Value

    If y = 7 Or 14 Or 21 Or 27 Then
        x = x + 0.5
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `x = x + (Abs(y Mod 7 = 0) * 0.5)`  No real need for the if.  Is the 27 meant to be 28 also?  What do you mean by "did not work"?

Comment: Use the formula that Nathan_Sav wrote. Beside this: If you have a question, don't write "It doesn't work". Tell exactly what it should do and what is does instead. In your case, the problem is obvious: x is declared as Integer. If you add 0.5 to an integer, VBA needs to round - 0.5 will be rounded to 1. You should learn to use the debugger, this will reveal such a problem really quick.

Comment: Also note that `If y = 7 Or 14 Or 21 Or 27 Then` needs to be `If y = 7 Or y = 14 Or y = 21 Or y = 27 Then` to be a valid `If` statement. What you wrote is the same as `If y = 7 Or 14 = True Or 21 = True Or 27 = True Then` and that is very likely not what you meant. • Any your `Sub ()` needs a name `Sub MyProcedureName ()`

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change datatype `Integer` to `Double` like FunThomas wrote.
Then you should add `Range("e2").Value = x` before `Else`.

Comment: Your solution was good but I needed the value of x to be a cumulative value and that didn't happen